# MVVM Foundation vs MVVM Toolkit

Tags: .net, mvvm-toolkit, mvvm-foundation

Can someone explain the differences between the [MVVM Foundation](http://mvvmfoundation.codeplex.com/) and the [MVVM Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=WPF%20Model-View-ViewModel%20Toolkit)? They seem to have a lot in common.

Comment: Have you put either of them into use, yet?  Do you have any personal experiences with either that you can share with us now?  I'm in the same boat as you.

Answer (score 4):

[MVVM Foundation](http://mvvmfoundation.codeplex.com/) is created and maintained by single person while [MVVM Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=WPF%20Model-View-ViewModel%20Toolkit) is part of a much larger package developed by people from Microsoft. I'm not saying which is the better - just pointing out this fact.

Comment: Six months later, the page of MVVM Toolkit shows no signs of life.

Comment: Things go back and forward, Toolkit updated Feb. 2010 while Foundation is updated Aug. 2009

Answer (score 1):

MVVM Foundation is a thin, simple, open source MVVM architecture library. It includes alot of the basic plumbing code required for INotifyPropertyChanged and binding to Commands. Its most useful feature is the Mediator pattern implementation for both Wpf and Silverlight, which allows weak reference eventing between view models, which is indespensible if you're using MVVM. I've used it in all my Silverlight projects.